# Помогите реализовать удаление записи на ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Вот html генерируетса таблица и виводит дание
снизу есть форма черес которую записи можно добавть но надо сразу удалять при необходимости

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
success: function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#table-get-kre').empty();
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      table_kred = "<tr><td style='text-align: left'>" + item.description + "</td><td>" + item.grn + "</td><td>" + item.pln + "</td><td>" + item.eur + "</td><td>" + item.usd + "</td><td><a href='#' data-id='" + item.id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a></td></tr>";
      $('#table-get-kre').append($(table_kred));
    })
    // удаление
    $('.delete-kredit').bind('click', function() {
      var id_delete = $(".delete-kredit").attr('data-id');
      console.log(id_delete);
      deleteTableKredit(id_delete);
    });
    // удаление
  })
},
```

вот php

```
<?php
include ("include/config.php");

    $idDeleteItem = intval($idDeleteItem);
    $queryDelete = "DELETE FROM `credit` WHERE `id` = $idDeleteItem";
    $deleteKredit = mysqli_query($conection, $queryDelete);
```

Comment: добавте `html` разметку и пример данных, по которым строится таблица, и тогда, возможно вам помогут. + вопрос, проблема в том чтобы удалить запись с таблицы на страничке ? и что такое `deleteTableKredit` ?

Comment: Добавил еще инфу

Comment: @AlexKizyma картинками добавлять плохая идея, лучше добавить код, а лучше вообще сниппет который будет работать и отображать проблему, спрошу, еще раз, вы не можете понять как удалить рядок с таблицы ?

Comment: Для начала ответьте на пару вопросов: 1. php получает данные от скрипта через аякс? 2. на что ругается mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Не надо пытатся вешать обработчик события на каждую строку во время ее создания, делегируйте события через [`$(document).on('event_name', 'event_target', function(){});`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Вот примерный способ удаление строки с таблицы (ajax на удаление из базы добавите сами) :

```js
var items = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "desc 1",
    grn: 1,
    pln: 1,
    eur: 1,
    usd: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "desc 2",
    grn: 2,
    pln: 2,
    eur: 2,
    usd: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "desc 3",
    grn: 3,
    pln: 3,
    eur: 3,
    usd: 3
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  table_kred = "<tr class='as_123'><td style='text-align: left'>" + items[i].description + "</td><td>" + items[i].grn + "</td><td>" + items[i].pln + "</td><td>" + items[i].eur + "</td><td>" + items[i].usd + "</td><td><a href='#' data-id='" + items[i].id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a></td></tr>";
  $('#table-get-kre').append($(table_kred));
}

$(document).on('click', '.delete-kredit', function() {
  var a = $(this).attr('data-id');
  console.log(a);
  var row = $(this).closest('td').parent();
  // тут запускаете ajax запрос, в котором на success выполняете удаление рядка :
  row.remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-get-kre"></table>
```